# Question about making a book like the contacts book on the iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

For any of you out there who have had a chance to download the iPhone 3.2 sdk and play around with the simulator knows that one of the apps built in is a contacts book. When you open this app up it looks like a book, and has a nice user friendly way to edit and view contacts. So if I wanted to make an app that uses a similar format, meaning I'd want it to be a book, that would allow for editing and viewing of different items. How would I do that? Is there a book template I just don't know about? :) I'm guessing that the book is just a nice photoshopped image that they are just laying the respective uiviews over the image but I may be wrong...any insights as to how I'd be able to implement a book as described would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: There is an undocumented class `UIBookViewController` for this. :p

Comment: Not to mention the iPhone screen is too small for this type of workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I recently built an app that had a "contacts" functionality.  I personally didn't want a book, so instead using photoshop, created a clipboard image for my background.  The background they are using that looks like a book, is just that, a background image.  they have other views and functionality built into the view controllers to make it slide around for editing.